# Why PPO does not correct the value by the importance sampling ratio

Tags: reinforcement-learning, actor-critic

I'm referring to this image present on [this page](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/ppo.html) :

[image]

My question is, why we don't correct $R_t$ with the importance sampling ratio? At the end of the day, that return is sampled according to $\pi_{old}$, not $\pi$...